# SVG animations only start after page is completely loaded. Is it true?

Tags: html, animation, svg

I just started playing with SVG animation. I would like for an animation to start as soon as possible but it seems animations only start after the page is completely loaded, including images. Is that true? Could someone confirm that? Anyway around it?

I created a fiddle that includes a big image (1.7MB) as an example. Please check it out: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8mu69Lm5/2/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="100">      
  <rect x="150" y="20" width="60" height="60" fill="blue" transform="rotate(91.0292 180 50)">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 180 50" to="360 180 50" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>  
</svg>
<img src="http://images6.alphacoders.com/370/370399.jpg">
```

UPDATE: clear the cache and then hit RUN because jsfiddle will preload the image

Comment: Have you tried the `begin` attribute?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin

Comment: Yes! It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

As my practice, `<animateTransform>` doesn't work onload. Maybe there is any way for force to work, but I don't know about it. 
I share you my way:
I use css animation for it:
I add `rotate` animation:

```
@keyframes rotate {
   100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

And add `mysvg` id to svg block and delete `animateTransform`, change x from 150 to 120 because of (widthsvg-widthrect)/2 = (300-60)/2 = 120.

```
<svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="100">      
    <rect x="120" y="20" width="60" height="60" fill="blue"></rect>
</svg>
<img src="http://images6.alphacoders.com/370/370399.jpg">
```

Combining `rotate` animation with `mysvg` id

```
#mysvg {animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;}
```

So summary https://jsfiddle.net/tv01kbwm/

Comment: Let me know, if it helps?